# ¿Cómo usar el prefijo 'N' para Unicode con la variable nvarchar

Tags: sql-server

Prefijo 'N' para Unicode con la variable nvarchar en un procedimiento almacenado insertar  para que me tome insersiones griegas  sqlserver

```
create TABLE dbo.DarwinPruebas ( PersonID smallint NOT NULL, FirstName nvarchar(25), LastName nvarchar(30) , BirthDate date, AnnualSalary money );

declare @FirstName nvarchar(25)='διαδικτυακά', @LastName nvarchar(25)='διαδικτυακά'

INSERT DarwinPruebas VALUES (2, @FirstName,@LastName, '02-23-1980', 65000.00)
```

Comment: puedes tratar de escribir la pregunta de forma que se entienda lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: estoy tratando de ingresar palabras en griego, pero cuando estoy ingresando no me deja 

INSERT DarwinPruebas
VALUES 
(2, @FirstName,@LastName, '02-23-1980', 65000.00)

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta.

Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Vale, te ayudo moviendo tu código a la pregunta. Enfoquémonos en la pregunta, que sea una buena pregunta y te podamos ayudar. Ya los moderadores nos ayudarán con la no-respuesta :)  Qué pasa cuando corres esas consultas? Cómo se ven esos datos? Te sale algún error? QUé versión de SQL Server usas? Por favor, POR FAVOR, responde usando la opción [edit] para añadir la respuesta a estas preguntas :D

Comment: Seria bueno que pongas el sp que estas usando, y como los esta insertando ahora, para tratar de ayudarte, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Esto es mucho más simple de lo que piensas, simplemente agregas la `N` antes del string:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DarwinPruebas ( PersonID smallint NOT NULL, FirstName nvarchar(25), LastName nvarchar(30) , BirthDate date, AnnualSalary money );

DECLARE @FirstName nvarchar(25)=N'διαδικτυακά', @LastName nvarchar(25)=N'διαδικτυακά';

INSERT DarwinPruebas VALUES (2, @FirstName,@LastName, '02-23-1980', 65000.00);
```

Comment: si pero si quiero que sea automatico  por que es insertar para llamarlo desde asp.net

Comment: si pero si quiero que sea automatico por que se llama el prcedimiento insertar desde el asp.net

Comment: cómo?, sorry, no entiendo tu nueva pregunta. En todo caso, suena a algo que tienes que configurar en asp.net

Comment: como hago  para asignarle a la variable como algo asi N@FirstName